# Module not found, webpack alias with typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, alias

I'm trying to implement some alias in webpack. What I want to do, is that instead of using this to import a component on App.js from the folder components.

`./components/layout/Header/Header`

I want this:

`@components/layout/Header/Header`

That is, in order to avoid problems when future nested folders will be created. What I've done is coding this on the **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'],
        alias: {
          src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
          assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
          components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```

And this on the **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src/*"],
      "@assets": ["./src/assets/*"],
      "@components": ["./src/components/*"]
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

When I run "npm run start" that is a "react-scripts start", I get the following error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@components/layout/Header/Header' in 'C:\Users\Angel\Documents\React\thermometer\src'
```

Also, I've noticed that when I run "npm run start", the object "paths" that I've created on the tsconfig.json file, **is deleted and the file resets**. I am new creating react projects from zero. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/), it doesn't mention automatically prepending the alias with `@`. Since it isn't specified there, Webpack (and therefore `react-scripts start`) doesn't know what `@components` points to.

I actually don't know whether Webpack supports aliases starting with `@` (e.g. a suffix of `$` has specific meaning for Webpack, and `@` is usually for scoped packages), but if it does, you'll have to alter your `resolve.alias` to include the `@`.

Comment: I've tried withouth the "@" and I get the same error :(

Comment: Then I guess Webpack just doesn't allow prefixing your packages with `@`, or at least not in that way. You could get rid of the `@` and use e.g. `components/layout/...`. Otherwise looking for or creating an issue on the Webpack repository might help you find something better, or at least let them know about this issue.

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to get the @ prefix to work in webpack 5 but nothing worked, I'll just switch to ~ for now...

Answer (score 0):

There is no prepending from webpack to aliases, you need to update your aliases to use the same path keys as the jsconfig/tsconfig.

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'],
        alias: {
          '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
          '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
          '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```